# Swift: Unexpected outcome in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView with the cells in sections rather than rows, with a total of 5 cells. Each cell has a button, and I want the fifth cells button (tableButton) to have a different title to the rest.

This is all working fine with the code I have below, the first 4 cells initially have the correct titles as per the code. However when I scroll down the the 5th cell (which has the expected title) and then scroll back up to the first cell, the first cell has now changed to the title that was meant to be specific to the fifth cell.

I added a print statement into the if cell.tableButton.tag == 4 conditional and it gets printed every time I scroll down to the fifth cell.

```
import UIKit
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        cell.tableButton.tag = indexPath.section
        if indexPath.section == 4 {
            cell.tableTitle.isHidden = true
            cell.tableButton.setTitle("Special", for: .normal)
        }  else {
            cell.tableButton.setTitle("Normal", for: .normal)
        }

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 15))
        returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground

        return returnedView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 15
    }
}
```

**CustomCell.swift:**

```
import UIKit
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe the state of the cell has changed. Replace `.normal` with `[]` for all cases

Comment: u have 5 sections with 5 cells?

Comment: 5 sections with 1 cell each, a total of 5 cells.

Comment: Its because the 5th cell is getting reused due to this line `dequeueReusableCell` in place of 1st cell.

Comment: penatheboss, I have just tried experimenting with this by making a label in the cell hidden if the indexPath.section == 4. The first cells title also disappears when I scroll back up so the state of the cell isnt causing the issue.

Comment: So I shouldnt dequeue the cells? I thought this leads to memory issues? How come it is only affecting the first cell when I scroll back up and not the others?

Comment: `cell.cellTitle.is hidden` Is this required or for debugging purpose?

Comment: cell.cellTitle.is hidden was just for demonstration that the cells state was not the cause of the issue, it is not required.

Comment: try condition `indexPath.section == 4` rather than checking `cell.tableButton.tag == 4`

Comment: I have tried that and received the same result.

Comment: What is the content of your `CustomCell`. I have re-created your scenario and I do not have the problem. You _Should_ use `dequeueReusableCell`, otherwise you will end up with a shit load of unnecessary cells in memory.

Comment: The problem must be that the cell is not preparing correctly for the reuse. Overriding the method `prepareForReuse` in the custom cell and setting everything to its initial state should do the work.

Comment: Either that, or another method is overriding the cells content. Either in the cell itself or maybe using e.g. `willDisplayCell`? A good thing would be to set breakpoints in the loading of the table and its content.

Comment: I've added the CustomCell contents. Adding prepareForResuse and reseting the title of the button isnt fixing the issue.

Comment: What more are you doing in your tableview view? Can you post the whole class? Maybe format the code in XCode first using CMD+A and then CTRL+i?

Comment: I think it would be good to change these comments into a chat, Question comment section is not meant to be used for chat.

Comment: I've added the full code with everything to do with the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens because you are using the `dequeReusableCell` method. Since you have only 5 cells in your tableview I don't think it would harm you if you not deque the cells anymore but instead create a new instance of your cell every time. It's not a best practice but it's an easy solution!

Comment: This is not a good approach...as it will pile up the memory usage.

Comment: Well he can also use the `prepareForReuse` method but since the number of cells in his tableview is static and it's only 5 cells I though this would be the easier solution for him without causing much harm.

Comment: He should not use `prepareForReuse` to set the cells content. That delegate method is not meant for that. The table view's delegate in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` should _always_ reset all content when reusing a cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your scenario, but I have no issues getting it working. I guess it might have to do with something in your `CustomCell`.

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        if indexPath.section == 4 {
            cell.tableButton.setTitle("Special", for: .normal)
        } else {
            cell.tableButton.setTitle("Normal", for: .normal)
        }

        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 250
    }
}
```

**CustomCell.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableButton: UIButton!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        tableButton.setTitle("RESET", for: .normal)
    }    
}
```

Of course, this a simplified implementation of a `UITableView`, but add more of your code to the example and maybe others can see or recreate your problem.

Comment: If I added two different actions (one for the "special" button and one for the "Normal" button called specialAction and normalAction) how can I use prepareForResuse to make the cells behave as they should as at the moment the first cell is peforming both actions!

Comment: Dont worry I've fixed it my removing the targets from the button in prepareForReuse!

Comment: The method `PrepareForReuse` is meant for resetting the cell to a state which is proper for reuse, not for setting the new data. If, at worst, your cell still behaves incorrectly, you could set the cell's content in `willDisplayCell` delegate method in your `UITableView`. Sorry for the late reply, _life_ got in between ;)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a cell reuse problem, since you are reusing your cells by using `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)`

You have several solutions here. The first would be to not reuse and create a new one, but that would be bad performance-wise, since more memory would be used.

A better solution to this would be to prepare for the reuse in the tableViewCell. You should override the method `prepareForReuse` in you custom tableViewCell. In that method, set the view to it's initial state (texts, alphas, etc). Just remember to call `super.prepareForReuse` first.

Comment: It is a very good approach to use `prepareForReuse`, however that is and _should_ not be a precondition to get this to work. The `UITableViewDelegate` should call the `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, which in its turn will get the cell (new or dequeued) and will change the value of `tableButton` on it.

Comment: Thanks, this method works for resetting the buttons title. How can this also be used for the buttons actions? If I give the "special" button an action that is different to the others, then the first cell actually peforms both the normal and special actions.

Comment: How are you setting the actions for the buttons?? It's not visible in the code